# how to have seperate contribution pages for each membership type.?

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

i have 3 membership types.  below is the screen shot
[image]

so if a users wants to pick one of the memberships  same contribution page opens up with a list of 3 membership types.

i don't want this list to be displayed at all.how can i do this so that picking up any one leads to the contribution page and no list ,may be selected membership type in hidden .
is there hook available for attaching membership type before final contribution.??

i am not getting 'Receipt ' on successful contibution. as i have configured receipt message properly .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 3 contribution pages, each having single membership type(selected under Memberships tab of contribution page) and set it to default and change the link(boxes from the screenshot) to use respective contribution page.

To hide the option you can use JS or CSS.

[image]

For emails not getting send make sure you have configured everything correctly like
1. Postfix package
2. From address in CiviCRM (CiviCRM >> Administer >> CiviMail >> From Email Address)
3. Updated the default mail accounts (CiviCRM >> Administer >> CiviMail >> Mail Accounts)
4. Updated Organization Address and Contact Info (CiviCRM >> Administer >> Comminications >> Organization Address and Contact Info

Probably looking  in Civi or CMS or apache logs for any suspicious errors might help to find the problem.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Hi @Pradeep Nayak thanks, yes this is one of the solution .

1>Can you please tell why is it that 'free' membership sign up doesn't work , while checking 'enable transaction' checkbox only works.

2> should i have to get emails settings proper then only i could get 'Receipt ' messgae or page . Doesn't it comes on each 'confirm contribution'.

Comment: Yes you need to enable 'Execute real-time monetary transactions' even if its a free membership unfortunately because any one is allowed to alter through hook the price of membership and the form needs to build payment block in such case. Yes please try if you can send normal php mail from your server.

Comment: thanks @Pradeep Nayak. So , it means for a free membership i need to charge atleast $0 and have the 'Execute real-time monetary transaction' enabled right.?

thanks once again anyway .

Comment: Yes! You got me now

Comment: Hello @Pradeep Nayak . 
Is it possible in civicrm to create a structure where .
there is a main Branch 
this BRANCH has 4-5 sub branches BRANCH1,BRANCH2,BRANCH3,BRANCH4,BRANCH5
each of sub branches has 4-5 membership type. how to create this structure.??